# Not able to deploy with capistrano to aws from bitbucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I try to automate deployment of Ruby on Rails application to AWS EC2 instance from the repository on bitbucket using Capistrano on local machine. I tried ssh, password, no password, forward ssh keys, use unique ssh keys without fowarding. Everytime I face with this ssh trace 
`set :ssh_options, {
  verbose: :debug
} :debug`

> `D, [2016-01-15T21:08:45.830590 #8129] DEBUG -- socket[2aefc98b29bc]: queueing packet nr 52 type 97 len 28
>   I, [2016-01-15T21:08:45.830677 #8129]  INFO -- net.ssh.connection.session[2aefc9c83b04]: ec2-23-289-88-231.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com delete channel 2 which closed locally and remotely
>   INFO [b3dd32b6] Finished in 0.255 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
>   cap aborted!
>   Errno::ENETUNREACH: Network is unreachable - connect(2)
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb:65:in`connect'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb:65:in `connect_internal'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb:140:in`connect'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb:343:in `block in tcp'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb:232:in`each'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb:232:in `foreach'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb:333:in`tcp'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `initialize'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:225:in`new'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:225:in `start'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:95:in`call'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:95:in `create_new_entry'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:38:in`checkout'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:134:in `with_ssh'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:87:in`execute_command'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:121:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:121:in`tap'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:121:in `create_command_and_execute'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:53:in`execute'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:15:in`instance_exec'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:15:in `run'
>   /home/al/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p647/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.8.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in`block (2 levels) in execute'
>   Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
>   The deploy has failed with an error: #
>   ** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
>   ** Execute deploy:failed
>   al@al-machine:/media/al/E02EF2032EF1D290/projects/project$ cap aborted!
>   `
>   ```

Please suggest what to try

This is deploy.rb

```
`
lock '3.2.1'
set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:user/application.git'
set :branch, 'staging'
set :ssh_options, {
  verbose: :debug
}
 set :deploy_to, 'myfolder'
 set :scm, :git
 set :pty, true
 set :keep_releases, 5
set :use_sudo, true
set :rails_env, 'develop'
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :stages, ["staging", "production"]
set :default_stage, 'staging'
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end
  #after :publishing, :restart
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end
after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
`
```

This is staging.rb

```
`
role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}
role :web, %w{deploy@example.com}
role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}
set :deploy_to, "/myfolder"
 server 'ec2-my-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com',
   user: 'ec2-user',
   port: '22',
   roles: %w{web app db},
   :primary => true,
   ssh_options: {
    user: 'ec2-user', # overrides user setting above
     keys: %w(/home/local_machine_user/.ssh/aws_ssh_key_pair.pem),
     forward_agent: false,
     auth_methods: %w(publickey password),
     password: 'please use keys'
   }
`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a network issue:

```
Errno::ENETUNREACH: Network is unreachable - connect(2)
```

Check your security group and make sure that you permit the instance to connect to external sources on port 22. (You can also test it from that instance with "ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org".)

Comment: I can clone repository from bitbucket to EC2 under ssh connection  manually and with both keys (aws or local machine). It clones fine. I tried to swap keys, everything works but not through Capistrano. Security groups totally opened for now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  For me I missed changing out the example.com addresses.  So your staging.rb should look like:

`role :app, %w{deploy@ec2-my-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com}
    role :web, %w{deploy@ec2-my-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com}
    role :db,  %w{deploy@ec2-my-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com}
    set :deploy_to, "/myfolder"
    server 'ec2-my-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com',
    user: 'ec2-user',
    port: '22',
    roles: %w{web app db},
    :primary => true,
    ssh_options: {
        user: 'ec2-user', # overrides user setting above
        keys: %w(/home/local_machine_user/.ssh/aws_ssh_key_pair.pem),
        forward_agent: false,
        auth_methods: %w(publickey password),
        password: 'please use keys'
    }`